# angular-ui-router not working as expected

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I think that my code is correct, but it doesn't work right. It doesn't show a description of the About page.

I tried to write both through `.state('home.about')` and through parent: "home". Unfortunately it didn't work.

Ho can I get this to work?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.12/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.9"></script>
    <script data-require="ui-router@0.4.2" data-semver="0.4.2" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.4.2/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="usersApp">
    <a ui-sref="home" ui-sref-active="active">Home</a> 
    <a ui-sref="home.about" ui-sref-active="active">About</a> 
    <ui-view></ui-view>
    <script>
      
    var app = angular.module('usersApp', ['ui.router']);

    app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
      
      $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');
      
        $stateProvider
          .state('home', {
            url: '/home',
            template: '<h3>Home page</h3>'
          })
          .state('home.about', {
            url: '/about',
            template: '<h3>Home page / About page</h3>'
          });

    });
    
      
      
    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please don't post code on off-site resources. You can post normal code directly in your question and then format it using Ctrl+K or the `{}` button. For runnable HTML / JS / CSS code you can use Ctrl+M or the "JavaScript/HTML/CSS snippet" button.

Comment: Thanks! This's my first post here) I will follow the rules, I promise ;)

Answer (score 0):

because you are making about a child route of home you then the home template would need a ui-view element.  so your two options are

1. add ui-view to the home template

   #### Home page
2. move about state out of home hierarchy.

   .state('about')

   ui-sref="about"

Comment: the 'Home Page' was supposed to be code sample.  '<h3>Home page</h3><div ui-view></div>'

Comment: Thanks! it helped ;)

Answer (score 0):

Since `home.about` is a child state of `home`, you need to have a `ui-view` present in the template of `home` state.

Refer to the following snippet, which works after this change:

```js
var app = angular.module('usersApp', ['ui.router']);

app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');

  $stateProvider
    .state('home', {
      url: '/home',
      template: '<h3>Home page</h3><ui-view></ui-view>'
    })
    .state('home.about', {
      url: '/about',
      template: '<h3>Home page / About page</h3>'
    });

});
```

```html
<script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.12/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.9"></script>
<script data-require="ui-router@0.4.2" data-semver="0.4.2" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.4.2/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="usersApp">
  <a ui-sref="home" ui-sref-active="active">Home</a>
  <a ui-sref="home.about" ui-sref-active="active">About</a>
  <ui-view></ui-view>
</div>
```

Alternatively, you can absolutely target the `ui-view` of `home` state using [named views](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views).

Comment: Thanks a lot! You are right, I forgot about a <ui-view></ui-view> directive, that must be added to a parent template.